# Winsock Programming - WsaGetSelectError,

Tags: c++, networking, winsock

Little problem with my Winsock programming, I am attempting to integrate a graphical interface with the ability to pass data in between two clients.

Basically, C is pressed and executes the first section of code then i will get a "Socket Error" which is given by the MsgBox in the second segment of code i have in here.

```
case 'C':
{
    if(!Connected)
    {
        connect(s,(LPSOCKADDR)&me,sa_size);
        break;
    }
}

case WM_SOCKET:
    if (WSAGETSELECTERROR(lParam))
    {
        cout << "Socket error\n";
        WSAGetLastError();
        MessageBox (hwnd,"Socket Error123","Information",MB_OK);
        PostQuitMessage (0);
        return 0;
    }
```

I don't really know what to try and fix this, I've been unable to find any help in regards to adding a graphical interface into the networking code i have at the moment(Which worked without the graphical portion implemented), Just looking for any help i can find at the moment.

Comment: Which error exactly are you getting? Could you change your code to output the error code from `WSAGetLastError` or the actual error through `FormatMessage`?

Comment: Well, infact i am getting no errors. It makes the MsgBox appear and and PostQuitMessage closes the program. If i remove the quit function and leave everything else as it is, The program continues as if nothing had happened.

Comment: This doesn't mean you're not receiving any errors; The fact the error popup is appearing means `WSAGETSELECTERROR(lParam)` is evaluating to non-zero, which sounds like an error to me.

Comment: hwnd 0x004105f2 {unused=??? } HWND__ *,
unused CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated, 
This is all i could find in regards to errors when run in debug mode and stepping through each line.

Comment: I'm not talking about compile errors, I'm talking about runtime errors, specifically the one or ones that cause the `MessageBox`call to happen.

Comment: At runtime, There seems to be a numerous amount of problems in finding files. "Cannot find or open the PDB file" Is listed 28 times and references a different .dll for each one.

Comment: What does **wsaGetLastError** return? That's what you need to know. There no point calling it with using its return value.

Answer (score 0):

Your `'C'` handler is missing a `break`/`return` statement when `Connected` is true, and your `WM_SOCKET` handler is missing a `break`/`return` statement when `WSAGETSELECTERROR()` returns 0.

Also, `WSAGetLastError()` is meaningless in `WM_SOCKET`.  You have to use the error code that `WSAGETSELECTERROR()` reports.

Try this:

```
case 'C':
{
    if (!Connected)
        connect(s,(LPSOCKADDR)&me,sa_size);
    break;
}

case WM_SOCKET:
    if (WSAGETSELECTERROR(lParam))
    {
        std::cout << "Socket error " << WSAGETSELECTERROR(lParam) << " on Event " << WSAGETSELECTEVENT(lParam) << std::endl;
        MessageBox (hwnd, TEXT("Socket Error"), TEXT("Information"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        PostQuitMessage (0);
        return 0;
    }
    break;
```